# How to set column as IGNORE CASE for H2 in the schema

Tags: h2db

Is there a way to set the column in the state schema to ignore case ? I understand there's an option to set H2 as "IGNORECASE=TRUE" but I don't see how I can specific only one column to be ignoreCase?

Comment: [varchar_ignorecase_type](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#varchar_ignorecase_type) in the manual

Comment: How you set in the schema? would it be columnDefinition=VARCHAR_IGNORECASE?

Comment: That's a **data type**. You create a table where the column is defined with that type. You can't define the type of a column in a "schema". A schema is only namespace without further attributes